# Contains V/s have.text Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have this html:

```
<button class="QCunh0zgr7f4UtqlzAfU" data-variant="outline" data-testid="my-test-id"><span>amount &gt; à 1 200,00 €</span></button>
```

When i do:
`cy.getBySel('my-test-id').contains('amount > à 1 200,00 €').click()`- Test fails saying:

`Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'amount > à 1 200,00 €' within the element: <button.QCunh0zgr7f4UtqlzAfU> but never did.`

But when i do:

`cy.getBySel('my-test-id').should('have.text', 'amount > à 1 200,00 €').click()` - Test passes

Why when i use have.text it works but fails when using contains..If it can pass in have.text it means that the text is correct right?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the string contains a non-breaking space between the `1` and the `2`.

If you're using VSCode, the editor will show you the char code is `U+202f`.

But if you try to paste just that code into the test, it still fails. I surmise that `.contains()` filters out the special characters.

There are 2 things I found will work:

**Use an ordinary space**

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="my-test-id"]')
  .contains('amount > à 1' + ' ' + '200,00 €')
  .click()
```

**Split the `.contains()` into two parts**

```js
cy.get('[data-testid="my-test-id"]')
  .contains('amount > à 1')
  .contains('200,00 €')
  .click()
```

---

***By the way***

Unrelated to your main problem, `.contains('amount > à 1' + ' ' + '200,00 €')` returns the `<span>` element not the `<button>` element.

But the `<span>` may not fire the click event.

You may have to specify the `<button>` explicitly in the contains command like this

```js
cy.contains('button[data-testid="my-test-id"]', 'amount > à 1' + ' ' + '200,00 €')
  .click()
```